# Global cache of strings in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to learn the "right" (or idiomatic) way to do some things in Rust, after a long long time using only languages with garbage collection. I've been trying to translate some Python code as an exercise, and I've across something that has left me wondering how to do it.

I have a program that fetches and processes a large amount of data - usually tens of millions of entries. Each entry has a tag (a small string), and there are hundreds of thousands of possible tags (it's a fixed set). But in this program, we never process data having more than like 50 different tags each time. So what I started think was: instead of duplicating these strings millions of times, could I have some kind of "global" cache? So that I could just have references to them, and avoid moving these strings all around as I move the entries?

I say global, but I don't necessarily mean exactly global, but maybe something inside some struct that lives for the duration of the whole program, which could have a HashSet with all the strings observed so far, and we could just reference these strings (a reference or a Rc pointer).

Since I know that my tags are quite small (less than 10 ascii characters most of the time), I'll probably just copy them, shouldn't be the bottleneck in my program. But what if they were a bit larger? Would it make sense to do something like I said?

Also, I know that since I'm parsing external data, I'll actually be parsing and creating these duplicated strings all the time, so just keeping it instead of discarding it wouldn't make much of a difference in terms of performance, but maybe I could reduce memory usage a lot by not duplicating these for each entry (if for example I'm keeping a lot of these in memory).

Sorry for the long text with lots of hypothetical ideas, I'm just more and more curious about memory management the more I learn about Rust!

Comment: Are you familiar with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning? Another approach, depending on your application, would be using a structure which performs optimisations for small strings like https://github.com/rust-analyzer/smol_str

Comment: The Rust compiler uses string interning a lot - implementation: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/43347397f7c5ca9a670a3bb3890c7187e24a52ab/compiler/rustc_span/src/symbol.rs#L1748

Comment: There are a couple of string interning crates. Most notably [string_cache](https://crates.io/crates/string_cache)

Comment: I had never heard of "String interning" before, that is just what I was looking for! Thanks a lot! Maybe I'll create an answer with everything you all mentioned!